# No rule to make target : Codeblocks

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks

I have installed Code::Blocks on Ubuntu Linux 12.10 and trying to use examples of Openframeworks. The HelloWorld and other programs that I write in Code::Blocks build and run fine.

However, when I open Code::Blocks workspace of an `empty example` of OpenFrameworks in Code::Blocks and try to build it, I get an error saying `No rule to make target ../../../libspoco/lib/linux64/libPocoNet.a needed by bin/emptyExample_debug`

I checked in the relative path and there's no folder named `linux64`, but there's only a folder named `linux` and perhaps that's why I am getting this error while trying to build. My question is how do change this rule? This linux64 problem might also be there in other projects, is there a universal place where this can be changed to 'linux' instead of 'linux64'

Comment: Obvious question is whether you have a 64 bit version of linux, and whther you installed the 64 bit version of Code::Blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your machine and codeblocks whether both are of same bit . one of the easiest way to avoid this conflict is install codeblocks from ubuntu software center .